# Can I pass in the select option name into a ngModelChange method in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, select, drop-down-menu

I have this select below and I want to pass in the name for the select option into industryChange(), not the value ($event). Is this possible? Passing industry.name in my example below doesn't work!

Here is my select

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="ceIndustry">Industry</label>
  <select class="form-control" 
       [(ngModel)]="ceModal.industryId" 
       name="ceIndustry" 
       #ceIndustry="ngModel" 
       required 
       (ngModelChange)="industryChange(industry.name)">
    <option [ngValue]=null>None selected</option>
    <option *ngFor="let industry of industryList" [value]="industry.code">{{industry.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can with ngValue

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="ceIndustry">Industry</label>
  <select class="form-control" 
       [(ngModel)]="ceModal.industryId" 
       name="ceIndustry" 
       #ceIndustry="ngModel" 
       required 
       (ngModelChange)="industryChange($event)">
    <option [ngValue]=null>None selected</option>
    <option *ngFor="let industry of industryList" [ngValue]="industry">{{industry.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

industryChange will recive the complete industry object. Then you can use the name.

Answer (score 0):

> please use (change) in your code

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="ceIndustry">Industry</label>
  <select class="form-control" 
       [(ngModel)]="ceModal.industryId" 
       name="ceIndustry" 
       #ceIndustry="ngModel" 
       required 
       (change)="industryChange($event.target.value)">
    <option [ngValue]=null>None selected</option>
    <option *ngFor="let industry of industryList" [value]="industry.name">{{industry.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```